# joint distribution using jacobian

Tags: trigonometry, probability-distributions, jacobian

> Given the joint pdf of $X_1$ and $X_2$ as $f(x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{\pi}I_{(x_1^2+x_2^2<1)}$, find the joint pdf of $Y_1=\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2}$ and $Y_2=\frac{X_1}{\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2}}$.

Here is my attempt.

I transformed $X_1$ and $X_2$ into polar coordinates as $X_1=R \cos{\Theta}$ and $X_2=R \sin{\Theta}$, obtaining the joint pdf of $R$ and $\Theta$ as
$pdf(r,\theta)=\frac{r}{\pi}I_{(0\leq r<1)}I_{(0\leq \theta<2\pi)}$.

Now I will define a function from $\{(r,\theta)^T:0\leq r <1, 0\leq \theta <2\pi\}$ to $\{(y_1,y_2)^T:0\leq y_1 <1, -1 \leq y_2 < 1\}$ as

$
\begin{cases}
y_1=r\\
y_2=\cos \theta
\end{cases}
$, $
\begin{cases}
r=y_1\\
\theta = \cos^{-1}y_2, 2\pi-\cos^{-1}y_2
\end{cases}
$

, whose Jacobian determinant is

$\det(\frac{\partial y}{\partial \omega})=
\det(
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & -\sin\theta
\end{bmatrix}
)
=-\sin\theta
$,

so that
$pdf(y_1,y_2) = \sum_{\theta:y_2=\cos \theta} pdf(r,\theta) {\lvert \det(\frac{\partial y}{\partial \omega}) \rvert }^{-1}$.

This is where I'm stuck: can I express $-\sin\theta$ in terms of $y_2$? How should I separate the cases?

Comment: No, you can't use only $y2$, the sign can't be determined. But in the case computing density function, which is always positive, you can. Besides I'd suggest directly calculating the Jacobian $\partial{Y}/\partial{X}$.